# How to set dynamic path to nuget references?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Here is the sample project structure:

```
{ ProjectA }
    { packages } <-- packages are created here
    { ProjectA }
        - ProjectA.csproj <-- references ProjectB and C.
        - packages.config
    - ProjectA.sln <-- contains all projects: A, B and C.

{ ProjectB }
    - ProjectB.csproj
    - packages.config

{ ProjectC }
    - ProjectC.csproj
    - packages.config   

*{ packages} <-- *When I manually paste packages here. So one level above ProjectB.csproj file, then ProjectB compiles.
```

ProjectA solution has all three projects: A, B and C. ProjectA reference ProjectB and ProjectC.

When I compile ProjectA (projects B and C are compiled as well), all nuget packages are downloaded into {packages} folder on the same level as solution file. The problem is that ProjectB is not compiling. Yes... only ProejctB. I'm not even gonna investigate why only one project compiles although their configuration is exactly the same. Anyway...

In both ProjectB and C, when I expand References dlls from nuget are seen as they were missing (with the yellow rectangle). Somehow ProjectC compiles anyway, but ProjectB doesn't. The errors says it can't find the reference which is clearly in the packages folder.

My question is, how do I program/configure that sentance (psuedo code):

***"Dear ProejctB, Please look for the references in the package folder generated on the same level as the solution file. The solution file, which is trying to compile you right now. Thank you"***

PS. So technically, the path to the dll (reference) will be kinda dynamic. It will change depending on which solution file is opening/compiling the project. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you check projects B and C in **Manage NuGet Package for Solution...** on each of the package dependencies? The References would be set automatically.

Comment: @Jasen I'm not sure If I understand. When I click on **Manage NuGet Package for Solution...** of ProjectB, I can see packages with "green check" in Installed tab. They were installed and put into the package folder where the solution is. It's just, when I look at Rereferences list they are listed with the yellow warning. The project generated it, but cannot see them :/

Comment: @Jasen when I paste the `packages` folder  (manually) on the same level as `ProjectB` folder (look at my edited question), so it's on the same level as "potential" solution file for ProjectB (although there is no ProjectB.sln file there) - it will compile. So -> ProjectB generated packages in one location and then it's looking for references in another location :///

Comment: If you invoke the tool on the solution, the package manager shows a grid with all projects under the solution -- each project has a check box. Sometimes after a fresh install you need to do a Restore Packages. But the reference setting is automatic. If you have problems you may need to unreference the package and uninstall it, then redo the package install.

Comment: Not gonna work. References will, same packages folder - will, nuget download - no. You need to have all projects on the same level. If you want different level, for each level you need solution. solution has `.nuget\nuget.config`. In there, you can set the `<config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\packages" />
    </config>`. you add `..\\` for each level down.

Comment: @Marshall, It seems the `<HintPath>` in the projectB project not match the location of packages folder. So, please have try to use `Update-Package –reinstall` in the Package Manager Console window for projectB. Then build the solution.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT thanks, but it's not the case. ProjectB and C are being used in different solutions. So I will have the same problem everytime I switch the solution. Like I said, the solution must be a variable. I think `$(SolutionDir)` is the best way to do it right now. It's not gonna be hard to convert to VS2017 after all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it is by setting `HintPath` to:

```
<HintPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages\...
```

in `.csproj` files of ProjectB and ProjectC. It literally means: *"look for the references in the package folder generated on the same level as the solution file. The solution file, which is trying to compile you right now"*

This problem was reported multiple times. I believe it was fixed [here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/1656). There is also [NuGetReferenceHintPathRewrite](https://github.com/jstangroome/NuGetReferenceHintPathRewrite), but I didn't test it.

Comment: $(SolutionDir) is defined only for build from IDE.

Comment: @UserName I'm actually building my apps from IDE only, so it looks good to me, and it works! I'm still exploring my options though

Comment: @Marshall This is interesting solution, but you need to remember, it will require manual work in .proj file every time you add nuget package. for those projects that not on the same level and nuget.config has set (or default)

Comment: @T.S yeah, I'm aware of that. But the good thing about that solution is I'm not "sacrificing" anything. I think that default path `<HintPath>..\packages\..` was actually meant to be `<HintPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages\...`. Until we switch to VS2017 I'll accept this answer. It's not ideal (it's temporary), but it was what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Since packages.config is slowly becoming deprecated, you could migrate your projects from packages.config to `ProjectReference`, where the NuGet packages are specified inside the csproj file and a shared global location is used to store the packages (and there aren't any references with `HintPath` that would need changing).

In VS 2017 version 15.7, there will be an option to migrate in the context menu of the references node (already available in the preview):

[image: migrate option]

`PackageReference` is already supported in VS 2017 since around 15.1 or 15.2, only the migration tool is in preview.

For new projects, VS 2017 (current version!) you can already select the default package reference style and allow for choosing it for new projects:

[image: package reference style selection]

Comment: We're still on the VS2015 and the `$(SolutionDir)` solution might be the best for us at this point. KISS, right? I will be back to this answer when I switch to VS2017. Thanks tough

Comment: Yeah $(SolutionDir) only works when building a solution so you may need to update the project file with a fallback if you want `msbuild my.csproj` to work. (Defaulting it for all projects is again easier in VS 2017 using a `Directory.Build.props`)

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I really appreciate your help. I'm gonna stay with the "solution" solution, cuz we don't have many projects like that so we fixed them already. For now, it's good. We will see in the future (I'm aware it might be temporary solution though).

Comment: np at all, please just include VS versions in questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Nuget 3.x has packages.config concept and in this package name & version are mentioned at 2 place (In package.config and in .csproj file)

Reference in package config should be like this:

```
<package id="NewtonsoftJson" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
```

Hint path in csproj should be like this:

```
<HintPath>..\packages\NewtonsoftJson.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
```

Here "..\packages" says go one level up(means at solution level) and look for "packages" folder.

You should verify that hint path is exists or not. and Package version should be same (9.0.1) in both the files(package.config and .csproj)

As your Porject C compiles successful, it seems some issue in the packages which is used by only ProjectB.

If you are still facing issue, please provide below detail for further analysis.

1. "package config"
2. "ProjectB.csproj"
3. msbuild compilation log, to know that in which package you
   are facing issue.

Comment: your answer doesn't resolve the issue of project folder levels in the same solution

Comment: Please provide "package config", "ProjectB.csproj" and compilation log